# How to validate the input type radio button using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to validate my radio button field using Angular.js .Let me explain with my code below.

```
<form name="myForm"  enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
<div>
<input type="radio"  ng-model="new" value="true" ng-required="!new"> new 
<input type="radio"  ng-model="new" value="false" ng-required="!new">Old
</div> 
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addData(myForm);"  value="Add" ng-show="myForm.$valid"/>
</form>
```

Here i need when user is not selecting any radio button the add button should not be visible to user.I did some coding but its not happening like that .Please help me.

Comment: Both inputs should be binded with same model..

Comment: i did as per you but still issue is there .

Comment: Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/hE2hVVmXsw6mCzcHZGqw?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);


app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.people = [{
        name: "John"
    }, {
        name: "Paul"
    }, {
        name: "George"
    }, {
        name: "Ringo"
    }];
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form name="myForm" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <p>Favorite Beatle</p>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="person in people">
            <label>{{person.name}}
                <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.name" name="name" value="{{person.name}}" required />
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <p><tt>myForm.$invalid: {{myForm.$invalid}}</tt></p>
    <button ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What does `$parent` do ? Will you mind explaining it a bit ? OP had static radio buttons, what is the point of using `array` and binding it in `ng-repeat` ?